# Android How to print image with TSC Alpha-3R printer?

Tags: android, printing, bitmap

I want to print an image with android bluetooth TSC Alpha-3R printer ?

Any one to work with this device? How can I print bitmap with this device ?

Code sample or Any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna use an end user solution like Hammer Print, so far one of the only and best support, but still not perfect.

I just got the device, but is not like ESC/POS that you'll find a lot of apps with support.

If you have any recomendation, I'll love to hear it.

Cheers!